# Как мне сделать такую же фиксацию блоков как на этом сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://cihadturhan.com
Наткнулся на портфолио, в котором хотел бы позаимствовать такую же фиксацию секции 
Мне надо , чтобы при одной прокрутке прокрутилось и зафиксировалось на другой секции.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: сама навигация это обычное фиксированное меню но к нему прикручен своего рода lava lamp и так же активный пункт меню которые берётся из href

Comment: Можно воспользоваться [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это то что мне нужно было!